# picklist in Custom Settings Alternative

Tags: custom-field, customsetting

i am using custom Settings and one field is of type Picklist. one option is to choose a text field and put a validation on this field if user enter this value then its accepted else not .any better alternative ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a validation rule, because they're not "real" objects, but you can set the settings as "protected" when you create them-- if they are in a managed package, only code in the package can create, modify, and delete the settings, so you are in total control of what values (and combinations thereof) are valid.

Comment: can we override default insertion page of custom settings or any detail page layout ??

Comment: If it's protected and in a managed package, it won't appear on the standard page, data loader, etc. You can use a custom tab (with Visualforce) or a custom weblink (for Configuration) to provide a link to page that will manage the settings.